# How to get attached image to taxonomy..?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am using taxonomy and I need to get attached image to taxonomy. I have renamed my wp-content folder. After that I cannot retrieve the image path. I used

```
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/renamed-folder/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_my_taxonomy_fields($set->term_id, 'upload_image'), '_wp_attached_file', true); ?>
```

So, my image code is

```
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/renamed-folder/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta((get_my_taxonomy_fields($set->term_id, 'upload_image'), '_wp_attached_file', true); ?>" alt="<?php echo $set->name;  ?>" />
```

How can I get the taxonomy attached image path..?

Comment: Taxonomies have not images attached to them, ¿How do you attach them? Are you using some plugin? You can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) to get the URL of any image if you know  its ID; or [`get_attached_fiile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) if you need the path in the file system of your server.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to reference the uploads directory use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

```
<?php
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); // Array of key => value pairs
/*
    $upload_dir now contains something like the following (if successful)
    Array (
        [path] => C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2010\05
        [url] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05
        [subdir] => /2010/05
        [basedir] => C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\uploads
        [baseurl] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads
        [error] =>
    )
    // Descriptions
    [path] - base directory and sub directory or full path to upload directory.
    [url] - base url and sub directory or absolute URL to upload directory.
    [subdir] - sub directory if uploads use year/month folders option is on.
    [basedir] - path without subdir.
    [baseurl] - URL path without subdir.
    [error] - set to false.
*/

echo $upload_dir['path'] . '<br />';
echo $upload_dir['url'] . '<br />';
echo $upload_dir['subdir'] . '<br />';
echo $upload_dir['basedir'] . '<br />';
echo $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '<br />';
echo $upload_dir['error'] . '<br />';

$upload_url = ( $upload_dir['url'] );
$upload_url_alt = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . $upload_dir['subdir'] );

// Now echo the final result
echo $upload_url . '<br />'; // Output - http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05

// Using year and month based folders, the below will be the same as the line above.
echo $upload_url_alt . '<br />'; // Output - http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05
?>
```